# PhpStorm 'Find in Path' doesn't search everywhere

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm-2017.2

I'm using PhpStorm 2017.2.4 on Win 8.1.

I'm trying to search for a string within every file in the project.

For that I've opened 'Find in Path', set the File mask to "*", selected the option "Recursively" and began typing.

It seems that the tool is limiting it search to maximum of 100 files, and thus doesn't find that which I'm looking for. If I limit the search to be below 100 files it will work, but that's pointless.

The filetype is not ignored and is added under settings and 'File Types'.

Should I use the Notepad++ 'Find in Files' search function instead, or does PhpStorm/IntelliJ-IDEA has a function like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the related issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-178771